# ¿Como puedo hacer que una Vista le pase a un controlador un List<Models>?, uno de los campos del Modelo es cargado por el usuario en la vista

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, cshtml

Tengo una vista que corresponde a una encuesta. La misma se carga con las preguntas y al mismo tiempo en la última columna tiene un DropDowList con las posibles respuestas. El problema que tengo es que no logro hacer que mi controlador reciba los datos de las preguntas y respuestas.

Vista:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("CompetenciasEspecificas", "VDTCabecera",Model, 
FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
<div id="block1">
    <fieldset>

        <legend class="text-center header">Competencias Cardinales</legend>
        <legend class="text-center header">@ViewBag.Message</legend>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<table class="table" style="table-layout:fixed">
    <tr>
        <th width="50" height="16">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item)
        </th>
        <th width="200" height="16">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descripcion)
        </th>
        <th width="100" height="16"></th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item)</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            @{
        List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "4 (Grado Alto)",
            Value = "4",
            Selected = true
        });
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "3 (Bueno por encima del estandar)",
            Value = "3"

        });
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "2 (Minimo necesario para el puesto)",
            Value = "2"

        });

        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "1 (Insatisfactorio)",
            Value = "1"

        });
            }

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Calificacion, listItems, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", Title = "Estado en el cual se encuentra la parametrización actual" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Calificacion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    }

</table>



<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Siguiente página" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Controlador:

```
public ActionResult CompetenciasEspecificas(List<VDTAnalisisHabReqModel> collection)        
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {




                HabilidadesRequeridasServices srvhab = new HabilidadesRequeridasServices();
                List<VDTAnalisisHabReqModel> list = new List<VDTAnalisisHabReqModel>();
                /*
                foreach (VDTAnalisisHabReqModel a in collection)
                {
                    srvhab.InsertarDetalleHabilidad(a);
                }
                */

                /*list = srvhab.ObtenerHabilidadesEspecificas(collection[0].FuncionarioId);

                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    list[i].DatosFuncionario = collection[0].DatosFuncionario;
                    list[i].VdtId = collection[0].VdtId;
                }


                ViewBag.Message = collection[0].DatosFuncionario;*/

                return View(list);

            }

            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: que hay en VDTAnalisisHabReqModel?

Comment: Solo propiedades de una tabla, datos básicos   
`public int HabilidadId { get; set; }
 public int CompetenciaId { get; set; }
 public string Orden { get; set; }
 public string Item { get; set; }
 public string Descripcion { get; set; }
 public string DatosFuncionario { get; set; }
 public string Calificacion { get; set; }
 public int VdtId { get; set; }
 public int FuncionarioId { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo en lo personal lo haría con Ajax así puedo armar mi model y enviarlo sin problemas.

Espero te sirva

**Tabla**

```html
<table id="tbl" style="width:100%" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>item</th>
        <th>Descripción</th>
        <th>
          Opción
        </th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Descripcion item 1</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">1 (Insatisfactorio)</option>
            <option value="2">2 (Minimo necesario para el puesto)</option>
            <option value="3">3 (Bueno por encima del estandar)</option>
            <option value="4">4 (Grado Alto)</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Descripcion item 2</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">1 (Insatisfactorio)</option>
            <option value="2">2 (Minimo necesario para el puesto)</option>
            <option value="3">3 (Bueno por encima del estandar)</option>
            <option value="4">4 (Grado Alto)</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

En el controlador cambia ActionResult por JsonResult.
Quedaría de la siguiente manera.

**Controlador**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CompetenciasEspecificas(SampleViewModel[] collection)
{                       
    return Json(new { model = collection});
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var modelArr = []; // Arra que se enviara al controlador

   $('#tbl tbody tr').each(function(){
      // Por cada row de la table   
   var obj = {
        Prop1: $(this).children('td').eq(0).text(),
        Prop2: $(this).children('td').eq(1).text(),
        Prop3: $(this).children('td').eq(2).find("select option:selected").val()
    };

        modelArr.push(obj); // Agregar objeto al modelArr 

    });

    $.ajax({
        url: $('form').attr('action'),
        data: {collection: modelArr},
        method: "POST",
        success: function (response){
            console.log(response);
            // Si todo salio bien hacer algo más
        },
        error: function(a){
            console.log(a);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Haz que el action del controller reciba como parametro el mismo tipo que el Model de la vista y te hará el binding bien. 
En esa clase del Modelo añadele la List VDTAnalisisHabReqModel como atributo y lo pondrá allí.

public ActionResult CompetenciasEspecificas(TipoDeLaVista collection)

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos, ya he podido hacer lo que buscaba, les dejo el código, utilizando JSON y cambiando la tabla por una grilla lo conseguí.

Vista :

Script:

```
$(function () {
    //$('.edit-mode').hide();
    $('.edit-user, .cancel-user').on('click', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        //tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
    });

    $('.save-user').on('click', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        var Item = tr.find("#lblItem").text();
        var Descripcion = tr.find("#lblDescripcion").html();
        var HabilidadId = tr.find("#lblhabilidadId").html();
        var Calificacion = tr.find("#calificacion").val();
        var VdtId = tr.find("#lblvdtId").html();
        tr.find("#lblItem").text(Item);
        tr.find("#lblItem").text(Item);
        tr.find("#lblDescripcion").text(Descripcion);
        // tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
        var VDTAnalisisHabReqModel =
            {
                "HabilidadId": HabilidadId,
                "Item": Item,
                "Descripcion": Descripcion,
                "Calificacion": Calificacion,
                "VdtId": VdtId
            };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/VDTCabecera/InsertarDetallesHabilidades/',
            data: JSON.stringify(VDTAnalisisHabReqModel),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
})
```

Vista

```
    @{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "4 (Grado Alto)",
        Value = "4",
        Selected = true
    });
    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "3 (Bueno por encima del estandar)",
        Value = "3"

    });
    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "2 (Minimo necesario para el puesto)",
        Value = "2"

    });

    listItems2.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "1 (Insatisfactorio)",
        Value = "1"

    });
}
@grid.GetHtml(
                                                tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                                                headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                                                footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                                                alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                                                selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
                                                rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                                                mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                                                columns:
                                                    grid.Columns(
                                                     grid.Column("", format: @<text>  <span style="display:none;">@item.HabilidadId </span> <label id="lblhabilidadId" hidden="hidden">@item.HabilidadId</label> </text>, style: "novisible"),
                                                                                                                                   grid.Column("Item", "ITEM", format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblItem">@item.Item</label> </span></text>, style: "item"),
                                                                                                                                                                                                          grid.Column("Descripcion", "COMPETENCIA", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblDescripcion">@item.Descripcion</label> </span> </text>, style: "competencia"),
                                                                                                                                                                                                   grid.Column("Calificacion", "CALIFICACIÓN", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("calificacion", listItems2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })),
                                                                                                                                                                                                   grid.Column("", format: @<text>  <span style="display:none;">@item.VdtId </span> <label id="lblvdtId" hidden="hidden">@item.VdtId</label> </text>, style: "novisible"),

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          grid.Column("", format: @<text>

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <button class="save-user display-mode btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </text>, style: "col3Width", canSort: false)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ))
```

Controlador:

```
    public JsonResult InsertarDetallesHabilidades(VDTAnalisisHabReqModel model)
    {
        // Update model to your db  
        HabilidadesRequeridasServices habServ = new HabilidadesRequeridasServices();
        string msj = habServ.InsertarDetalleHabilidad(model);
        string message = string.Empty;

        if (msj == "COMPELTO" || msj == "INCOMPLETO")
        {
            message = "El registro fue guardado con exito";
        }
        else
        {
            message = msj;
        }

        if (msj == "COMPLETO")
            ViewBag.Completo = "S";


        return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```